# Simplest screen echo server?

Tags: services, telnet

What is the simplest way to do the following thing?

Run a program which will open specified port, listen for it, and display whatever it receives. Also if type something -- then send back to connected peer.

This is for debug purposes.

Comment: You can use http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/nc-command-examples/ for the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Server listens on port 8000:

```
$ nc -l 8000
```

Client connects to port 8000:

```
$ nc localhost 8000
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The poster wanted to display what the client sends. The only way I see is to use the "-c" or "-e" option but I'm hoping there's a solution using only pipes.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [Gnu Netcat (nc)](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)